# how to pass parameter from one script to another script in `package.json`?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I'd like to create below scripts in `package.json`. The script `upload` is a general command to upload to `s3` bucket. It accepts bucket name as a parameter. Other two scripts pass in different bucket name for uploading. Below code doesn't work as expected. How can I make the script work for this case?

```
scripts: {
    "upload": "aws s3 cp build s3://$1 --grants",
    "upload:dev": "npm run upload -- test",
    "upload:prod": "npm run upload -- prod"
}
```

Comment: ideally all of them, or at least Linux and macOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "upload": "aws s3 cp build s3://$npm_config_bucket --grants",
    "upload:dev": "npm run upload --bucket=test",
    "upload:prod": "npm run upload --bucket=prod"
},
```

Comment: If you want this to run cross-platform via both Windows cmd.exe and *nix shells then consider additionally utilizing [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) to normalize how npm variables are referenced, i.e. `$npm_config_bucket` and `%npm_config_bucket%`